# Remove default padding in JTextPane on Windows

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextpane

For displaying information on a Java Swing GUI I use a mixture of `JLabel` components and `JTextPanes`.

As you can see in the following image, all labels are `JLabels` except for the one in the bottom right corner which is marked red and yellow. This one's a `JTextPane`, cause I don't know the text length before rendering and it has to wrap (which is not working in a `JLabel`, right?).

[image: Different Rendering on Windows and Mac]

The left column is aligned right and has a right-margin of 5, the right column is aligned left with zero margin.

In Eclipse WindowBuilder and on Windows 7 rendering, the `JTextPane` obviously has a small padding which I can't remove.

Surprisingly, this padding isn't shown on my Mac (Mountain Lion) and the `JTextPane` is aligned perfectly well.

Is there any way to achieve the same aligned look on Windows and on Mac? And why on earth does the `JTextPane` component has this annoying padding on windows?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `textPane.getMargin()/setMargin()`
but actually it's defined by L&F

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! `textPane.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0))` worked like a charm!